# Thermal Expansion and Contraction in Two Story Townhome

Tags: hvac, attic, hardwood-floor, noise, noise-reduction

I live in California in the city of Chatsworth to be exact. I live in a two story Townhome and for the most part when I sleep in my bedroom it's very quiet. Occasionally there will be nights sometimes two nights back to back that there will be loud pop and cracking noises from three to four areas. From the attic above mainly and the wood floor below. Mainly from the same areas. At first I thought it may have been a copper pipe but I have ruled out all pipes. I'm trying to study the historical weather in my city to see what causes it but I can't figure it out.

I have an attic above with two standard exhaust vents and a little bit of insulation laid out on the bottom of the attic directly above the bedroom walls.

I want to mention that when the noise occurs it's pretty much runs all throughout the night and up until noon. I have also ruled out any animals like squirrels and rodents.

Please help with any ideas to help minimize this problem.

Comment: Have you asked your neighbors if they have the same issue? This might be a problem that's already been solved.

Answer (score 1):

That's not right at all. Nothing should be constantly repeating or over that many hours. Usual sounds are just nails sliding in & out of their pockets, 1-pop or crack going in with the cold & 1-pop or crack coming out with the heat, for just a few nails or sounds total. Or, plastic & aluminum siding rustling momentarily in direct Sun. Maybe, it's just the screening on the vents that might be loose & flapping in the breeze.

Get a Carpenter out to check on whether something's actually broken & to sink a bunch of screws & get rid of the usual suspects. Screws don't need to join pieces, they can just span a gap & keep things from moving. Wall & ceiling cracks, if any, are a great indicator of movement areas. Or, it could be something electrical that contracts at night, the Carpenter might notice this, but get an Electrician too.